# Mysql change user to Editable Mode NOT read only mode

Tags: mysql

I m using SSH connect, to remote Mysql database.
unfortunately i can't edit the data, because the mode is READ ONLY,
i have tried grant all permission for user `root`, but still in READ ONLY mode,
how to change the READ ONLY mode to editable data mode?  [image]

Update

and tried `set GLOBAL read_only = false;`

Comment: Is the read_only variable set?

Comment: Did you granted permission with GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'

Comment: @winmutt how to set read_only variable set to false?

Comment: @anhlc Yes, I did...

Comment: @winmutt tried `set GLOBAL read_only = false;` also can't

Answer (score 1):

you can also read only on and off with a couple of methods

Method 1
read only on
SET GLOBAL read_only = ON;
read only off
SET GLOBAL read_only = OFF;

Method 2
read only on
update replicationstatus set writable=0;
read only off
update replicationstatus set writable=1;

Answer (score -1):

You can also set read-only on and off with a couple of different methods:

Method 1

```
#read only on
SET GLOBAL read_only = ON;
#read only off
SET GLOBAL read_only = OFF;
```

Method 2

```
#read only on
update replicationstatus set writable=0;
#read only off
update replicationstatus set writable=1;
```